# How can I upload keystore.jks into Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i have a keystore that I generated using Go Daddy's certificate, and it works as intended when using it localy with tomcat. but I cannot firgure out how to upload that keystore so be used by the amazon